# adding product in NSMuttable Array is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have below code where I am fetching data...

```
database=nil;
    if (sqlite3_open([sqlitePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){
        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from products"] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt)){
            //NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating database. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        while(sqlite3_step(updateStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSLog(@"ok=====");
            NSNumber *recordID = [NSNumber numberWithInt: sqlite3_column_int(updateStmt, 0)];
            NSString *fullName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(updateStmt, 1)];
            NSString *photoName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(updateStmt, 2)];

            NSLog(@"=====%@===%@====%@====", recordID, fullName, photoName);

            NSDictionary *product = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: recordID, @"id", fullName, @"fullName", photoName, @"photoName", nil];
            [products addObject: product];
            [product release];
        }

        NSLog(@"total data is ==== %d", [products count]);

        [numberFormatter release];

        sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);

    }
```

When I run this code, I get below output as below.

```
2013-07-25 14:12:14.785 SQLTest[88568:11303] =====2===test 002====21.45====
2013-07-25 14:12:14.786 SQLTest[88568:11303] =====4===test 002====21.45====
2013-07-25 14:12:14.786 SQLTest[88568:11303] =====6===test 002====22.16====
2013-07-25 14:12:14.787 SQLTest[88568:11303] =====7===test 002====22.17====
2013-07-25 14:12:14.787 SQLTest[88568:11303] total data is ==== 0
```

My Question is when I am adding data in `products` why I get `[products count]` as 0 instead of 4?

When I use `NSLog(@"print===%@", product);` I see below output (for all ids)

```
{
    fullName = "test 002";
    id = 7;
    photoName = "22.17";
}
```

Note

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) sqlite3 *database;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *products;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger currentProduct;
```

Comment: Have you allocated `products`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems;

You've not allocated your array, just declared a pointer to it. Add this to your init;

```
products = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You also are skipping the first row of your result by stepping twice before fetching data;

```
if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt)){     // <-- skips first row
    //NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating database. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
while(sqlite3_step(updateStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {   // Starts at second row
```

Answer (score 1):

allocate memory to `products` Array,

```
products = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: its working... but I am facing one problem... when I am pulling data, data is starting from second record... i am not getting first record.. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: your code looks fine but somewhere else may be you went wrong but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that products was never initialised, therefor your `[products addObject: product];` will result in a nil message that doesn't give any error but doesn't add anything to products either.

You can either init products in your class init:

```
- (id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      self.products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Or you can lazy loading products only the first time that it gets called:

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)products {
    if (!_products) _products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _products;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
database=nil;

    products = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //Paste this line  below database=nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not intializing the Product Array.

```
products = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You need to intialize first then do what you want.